# How to map the workspace in TFS programatically

Tags: c#, tfs, workspace, tfs-sdk

I'm working on Checking-In items to the TFS programatically. My code for mapping to workspace is

```
        Uri uri = new Uri(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["uri"]);
        teamProjectCollection = new TfsTeamProjectCollection(uri);            
        versionControlServer = teamProjectCollection.GetService<VersionControlServer>();                       
        workspace = versionControlServer.GetWorkspace(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["workspace"], versionControlServer.AuthorizedUser);
        workspace.Map(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["mappath"], folder);
```

Now I have mapped my folder to the TFS project. But if someone is already having a mapping my code isn't checking the items to TFS. So I would like to checkin items with my mapping if they already have a mapping. What should be done?

Answer (score 0):

You would need to remove any previous mappings for that location.

You should be able to iterate through the existing mapping for that machine and delete any that match your path.

Comment: It's probably workspace = versionControlServer.GetWorkspaces();